# Spring MVC Controller Request Mapping Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

After writing all the neccessary code to show a simple page with spring mvc I am getting a **HTTP 404 – Not Found**

server : Tomcat 8
IDE : Intelijj IDE

code package name : ma.financialforce;

***HomeController***

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-page";
    }
}
```

***web.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

***spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ma.financialforce" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

***main-page.jsp : ***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A jsp page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Run/debug config screenshot :*** this is a screenshot of my run/config for the app

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Does the log file show the web application started without error? What URL do you use when you get 404 Not Found?

Comment: @Andreas, yes it shows no error. now I changed the application context url to "/" and shows a page titled $Title$ and with content of $END$

Comment: What is in the JSP?

Comment: I have edited the post with the jsp page

Comment: @Andreas thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the intellij, under run/debug config, click on deployment tab and check what's the context root has been set. Intellij by default set context root as the project name and in your case there is no context root. So deployment tab should have context root as /

Comment: I changed deployment tab's Application context to "/". and now I am getting a page titled _$Title$_ and with content of _$END$_. so, the controller stills not working depsite of the logs which shows that the initialization of controller is completed

Comment: I assume when you are getting the page, you are getting your jsp page, that means it got request from dispatcher servlet through controller to jsp. Now to find out why title is coming as you mentioned..need the jsp code.